# Xamarin Android Alarm Manager Issue

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, alarmmanager

I have an `AlarmManager` in my Xamarin Android App. I'm configuring it using `SetExact()` with the time of 5 minutes. But it is being started after only five seconds. And no matter what time i'm configuring it with, it will always trigger after 5 seconds.
I've used the exact same code in Java, and it worked perfectly fine.

The code:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
    public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.Info("AlarmReceiver", "Triggered");
        }

        public static void Start(Context context, long triggerAfterMilis)
        {
            var type = AlarmType.RtcWakeup;
            var alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);

            var timerIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, typeof(AlarmReceiver)), PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

            alarmManager.Cancel(timerIntent);
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.M)
                alarmManager.SetAndAllowWhileIdle(type, triggerAfterMilis, timerIntent);
            else if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                alarmManager.SetExact(type, triggerAfterMilis, timerIntent);
            else
                alarmManager.Set(type, triggerAfterMilis, timerIntent);
            Log.Info("AlarmReceiver", $"Started, tigger after {triggerAfterMilis} miliseconds.");
        }
    }
```

How I'm using the `AlarmReceiver`:

```
AlarmReceiver.Start(Activity,(long)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalMilliseconds)
```

The output window:

> 14:14:20.217 5393-5393/AlarmReceiver: Started, tigger after 600000
>   miliseconds. 14:14:25.218 5393-5393/AlarmReceiver: Triggered

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @RaymonddelaCroix there you go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the time to trigger the alarm in the past by only using the timespan of 10 minutes, the number of milliseconds needs to be calculated from the beginning of the year 1970.

> If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately.

Get the current time, and add time to it.

```
var TenMinsFromNow = Calendar.GetInstance(Android.Icu.Util.TimeZone.Default).TimeInMillis + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalMilliseconds);
```

Current time in milliseconds from "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z":

```
 Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
```

Or:

```
 Calendar.GetInstance(Android.Icu.Util.TimeZone.Default).TimeInMillis;
```

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Alex Glad it help... ;-)

Comment: 2021 ALarmManager is not working anymore for Xamarin no mattr what you do!

Comment: @user1034912 Android's AlarmManager does still work via Xamarin, you should post a new question w/ your code and the problem you are having.