# How to set alarms in Xamarin using AlarmManager

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, alarmmanager, alarm

I have been using Xamarin to create an alarm application, but Android's built-in AlarmManager class doesn't seem to be working. I have assigned the alarm to initiate once a button is pressed, but instead of going off at the given time, it goes off as soon as the button is pressed:

```
        Intent myIntent;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;


        myIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, 0, myIntent, 0);
        manager.SetExact(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 30000, pendingIntent);
```

Through testing it seems like the 'triggerAtMillis" parameter of SetExact doesn't affect anything. This is my code for the alarm receiver:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled =true)]
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context, "channel id");

        builder.SetContentTitle("Alarm title")
            .SetContentText("This is the alarm")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.navigation_empty_icon)
            .SetChannelId("channel id")
            .SetTicker("API");

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);

        NotificationChannel mChannel = manager.GetNotificationChannel("default_channel_id");
        if (mChannel == null)
        {
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel("channel id", "channel description", NotificationImportance.High);
        }
        Notification notification = builder.Build();


        Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, "Alarm completed", ToastLength.Long).Show();

        manager.Notify(1, notification);
    }
}
```

I am very new to Android development so the answer may be more obvious than expected. Thanks.

Comment: Use CurrentTimeMillis or Calendar : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41064490/4984832

Comment: @SushiHangover from what i've found, the c# equivalent of CurrentTimeMillis is Environment.TickCount. Replacing the SetExact function as follows still gives the same result:

`manager.SetExact(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, System.Environment.TickCount + 300000, pendingIntent);`

Comment: Environment.TickCount is NOT the same, `Gets the number of milliseconds elapsed since the system started.`

Comment: @SushiHangover What would the C# equivalent of  CurrentTimeMillis be?

Comment: `DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds` but you are already using Xamarin.Android, you can just use CurrentTimeMillis or Calendar ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds?view=netframework-4.8 )

Comment: Ah, that did it. I didn't realize I could use Java methods, thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it worked out 